# How to change what PCRE regexp thinks are newlines in multi-line mode?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

With PCRE regular expressions in PHP, multi-line mode (`/m`) enables `^` and `$` to match the start and end of lines (separated by *newlines*) in the source text, as well as the start and end of the source text.

This appears to work great on Linux with `\n` (LF) being the newline separator, but fails on Windows with `\r\n` (CRLF).

Is there any way to change what PCRE thinks are newlines? Or to perhaps allow it to match either CRLF or LF in the same way that `$` matches the end of line/string?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$EOL = "\n";    // Linux LF
$SOURCE_TEXT = "one{$EOL}two{$EOL}three{$EOL}four";
if (preg_match('/^two$/m',$SOURCE_TEXT)) {
    echo 'Found match.';    // <<< RESULT
} else {
    echo 'Did not find match!';
}
```

RESULT: Success

```
$EOL = "\r\n";    // Windows CR+LF
$SOURCE_TEXT = "one{$EOL}two{$EOL}three{$EOL}four";
if (preg_match('/^two$/m',$SOURCE_TEXT)) {
    echo 'Found match.';
} else {
    echo 'Did not find match!';    // <<< RESULT
}
```

RESULT: Fail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try the `(*CRLF)` and related modifiers? They are detailed on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (under Newline/linebreak options) and seem to do the right thing in my testing. i.e. `'/(*CRLF)^two$/m'` should match the windows `\r\n` newlines. Also `(*ANYCRLF)` should match both linux and windows but I haven't tested this.

Comment: Yes, this works for me too (including `(*ANYCRLF)`) when specified at the start of the pattern. Note that these modifiers are available since PCRE 7.3, which [corresponds to PHP 5.2.5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.installation.php).

Answer (score 5):

> ***Note:*** The answer is only applicable to older PHP versions, when I wrote it, I was not aware of the sequences and modifiers that are available: `\R`, `(*BSR_ANYCRLF)` and `(*BSR_UNICODE)`. See as well the answer to: [**How to replace different newline styles in PHP the smartest way?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836692/367456)

In PHP it's not possible to specify the newline character-sequence(s) for PCRE regex patterns. The `m` modifier is looking for `\n` only, [that's documented](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). And there is no runtime setting available to make a change which would be possible in perl but that's not an option with PHP.

I normally just modify the string prior using it with `preg_match` and the like:

```
$subject = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $subject);
```

This might not be exactly what you're looking for but probably it helps.

**Edit:** Regarding the windows EOL example you've added to your question:

```
$EOL = "\r\n";    // Windows CR+LF
$SOURCE_TEXT = "one{$EOL}two{$EOL}three{$EOL}four";
if (preg_match('/^two$/m',$SOURCE_TEXT)) {
    echo 'Found match.';
} else {
    echo 'Did not find match!';    // <<< RESULT
}
```

This fails because in the text, there is a `\r` after `two`. So `two` is not at the end of a line, there is an additional character, `\r` before the end of the line (`$`).

The PHP manual clearly explains that only `\n` is considered as the character that specifies a line ending. `$` does consider `\n` only, so if you're looking for `two\r` at the end of a line, you need to change your pattern. That's the other option (instead of converting the text as suggested above).

Comment: I don't the documentation is particularly clear on this, all it states is: "If there are no "\n" characters in a subject string, or no occurrences of ^ or $ in a pattern, setting this modifier has no effect."

Comment: It clearly states that `\n` is the (only) newline-character-sequence reflected by the `m` modifier.

Comment: I added some explanation to the answer as well for the code you've added.

Comment: Yes, this certainly seems to be the case; thanks for the clarification. However, I don't believe this is clearly stated in the documentation, unless you have another source? The link you gave to the [Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), from which I quoted above does not _clearly_ state this, although it could perhaps be construed as loosely inferring this.

Comment: @w3d: Well I don't understand what to argue about. It specifies which character is treated as line ending for the `m` modifier. You even quoted that. As `\n` is the only character that makes a difference, how can you think another character than `\n` would make a difference as well? Why should the documentation only list a subset, not the superset? It *could* be, but that would be speculation. From what I read there I would not expect `\r\n` to be treated as line-ending in multiline mode. Especially as it's written that `\n` is treated as line-ending.

Answer (score 3):

Thats strange, I don't think that `$` (with m modifier) cares if there is a `\n` or `\r\n` as new line.

An idea to test this, add `\s*` before the `$`. `\s` is matching also newline characters and should match then the `\r` before the `\n` if this would be really the problem.
As long as its no problem if there are additional whitespaces at the end of the line, it shouldn't hurt.

Comment: Well I wouldn't have thought it should matter either, but my regex appears to fail matching the eol `\r\n`. The start of the line matches OK. I had assumed this was because the end character was `\r` and not `\n`? I've added an example to my question which appears to show this.  Thanks for the `\s*` suggestion - that does indeed appear to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where your data comes from - external and uncontrolled sources might provide quite messy data. A hint for those of you who are trying to fight off (or work around at least) the problem of matching a pattern correctly at the end ($) of any line in multiple lines mode (/m).

```
<?php 
// Various OS-es have various end line (a.k.a line break) chars:
// - Windows uses CR+LF (\r\n);
// - Linux LF (\n);
// - OSX CR (\r).
// And that's why single dollar meta assertion ($) sometimes fails with multiline modifier (/m) mode - possible bug in PHP 5.3.8 or just a "feature"(?).
$str="ABC ABC\n\n123 123\r\ndef def\rnop nop\r\n890 890\nQRS QRS\r\r~-_ ~-_";
//          C          3                   p          0                   _
$pat1='/\w$/mi';    // This works excellent in JavaScript (Firefox 7.0.1+)
$pat2='/\w\r?$/mi'; // Slightly better
$pat3='/\w\R?$/mi'; // Somehow disappointing according to php.net and pcre.org when used improperly
$pat4='/\w(?=\R)/i';    // Much better with allowed lookahead assertion (just to detect without capture) without multiline (/m) mode; note that with alternative for end of string ((?=\R|$)) it would grab all 7 elements as expected
$pat5='/\w\v?$/mi';
$pat6='/(*ANYCRLF)\w$/mi';  // Excellent but undocumented on php.net at the moment (described on pcre.org and en.wikipedia.org)
$n=preg_match_all($pat1, $str, $m1);
$o=preg_match_all($pat2, $str, $m2);
$p=preg_match_all($pat3, $str, $m3);
$r=preg_match_all($pat4, $str, $m4);
$s=preg_match_all($pat5, $str, $m5);
$t=preg_match_all($pat6, $str, $m6);
echo $str."\n1 !!! $pat1 ($n): ".print_r($m1[0], true)
    ."\n2 !!! $pat2 ($o): ".print_r($m2[0], true)
    ."\n3 !!! $pat3 ($p): ".print_r($m3[0], true)
    ."\n4 !!! $pat4 ($r): ".print_r($m4[0], true)
    ."\n5 !!! $pat5 ($s): ".print_r($m5[0], true)
    ."\n6 !!! $pat6 ($t): ".print_r($m6[0], true);
// Note the difference among the three very helpful escape sequences in $pat2 (\r), $pat3 and $pat4 (\R), $pat5 (\v) and altered newline option in $pat6 ((*ANYCRLF)) - for some applications at least.

/* The code above results in the following output:
ABC ABC

123 123
def def
nop nop
890 890
QRS QRS

~-_ ~-_
1 !!! /\w$/mi (3): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 0
    [2] => _
)

2 !!! /\w\r?$/mi (5): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 3
    [2] => p
    [3] => 0
    [4] => _
)

3 !!! /\w\R?$/mi (5): Array
(
    [0] => C

    [1] => 3
    [2] => p
    [3] => 0
    [4] => _
)

4 !!! /\w(?=\R)/i (6): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 3
    [2] => f
    [3] => p
    [4] => 0
    [5] => S
)

5 !!! /\w\v?$/mi (5): Array
(
    [0] => C

    [1] => 3
    [2] => p
    [3] => 0
    [4] => _
)

6 !!! /(*ANYCRLF)\w$/mi (7): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 3
    [2] => f
    [3] => p
    [4] => 0
    [5] => S
    [6] => _
)
 */
?>
```

Unfortunately, I haven't got any access to a server with the latest PHP version - my local PHP is 5.3.8 and my public host's PHP is version 5.2.17.