# How to replace different newline styles in PHP the smartest way?

Tags: php, replace, newline, unify

I have a text which might have different newline styles.
I want to replace all newlines '\r\n', '\n','\r' with the same newline (in this case \r\n ).

What's the fastest way to do this? My current solution looks like this which is way sucky:

```
    $sNicetext = str_replace("\r\n",'%%%%somthing%%%%', $sNicetext);
    $sNicetext = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array("\r\n","\r\n"), $sNicetext);
    $sNicetext = str_replace('%%%%somthing%%%%',"\r\n", $sNicetext);
```

Problem is that you can't do this with one replace because the \r\n will be duplicated to \r\n\r\n .

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you can try PHP_EOL, i believe that will change the newline based on the OS

Comment: Where did you get that if you replace '\r\n' with '\r\n' that you get '\r\n\r\n'?

Comment: @N.B. http://codepad.org/Qy6HpnLj

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('~\R~u', "\r\n", $string);
```

If you don't want to replace all Unicode newlines but only CRLF style ones, use:

```
$string = preg_replace('~(*BSR_ANYCRLF)\R~', "\r\n", $string);
```

`\R` matches these newlines, `u` is a modifier to treat the input string as UTF-8.

---

From the [PCRE docs](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> **What `\R` matches**
>
> By  default,  the  sequence \R in a pattern matches any Unicode newline
>         sequence, whatever has been selected as the line  ending  sequence.  If
>         you specify
>
> ```
>      --enable-bsr-anycrlf
> ```
>
> the  default  is changed so that \R matches only CR, LF, or CRLF. Whatever is selected when PCRE is built can be overridden when the  library
>         functions are called.

and

> **Newline sequences**
>
> Outside  a  character class, by default, the escape sequence \R matches
>          any Unicode newline sequence. In non-UTF-8 mode \R is equivalent to the
>          following:
>
> ```
>     (?>\r\n|\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\x85)
> ```
>
> This  is  an  example  of an "atomic group", details of which are given
>          below.  This particular group matches either the two-character sequence
>          CR  followed  by  LF,  or  one  of  the single characters LF (linefeed,
>          U+000A), VT (vertical tab, U+000B), FF (formfeed, U+000C), CR (carriage
>          return, U+000D), or NEL (next line, U+0085). The two-character sequence
>          is treated as a single unit that cannot be split.
>
> In UTF-8 mode, two additional characters whose codepoints  are  greater
>          than 255 are added: LS (line separator, U+2028) and PS (paragraph separator, U+2029).  Unicode character property support is not  needed  for
>          these characters to be recognized.
>
> It is possible to restrict \R to match only CR, LF, or CRLF (instead of
>          the complete set  of  Unicode  line  endings)  by  setting  the  option
>          PCRE_BSR_ANYCRLF either at compile time or when the pattern is matched.
>          (BSR is an abbrevation for "backslash R".) This can be made the default
>          when  PCRE  is  built;  if this is the case, the other behaviour can be
>          requested via the PCRE_BSR_UNICODE option.   It  is  also  possible  to
>          specify  these  settings  by  starting a pattern string with one of the
>          following sequences:
>
> ```
>     (*BSR_ANYCRLF)   CR, LF, or CRLF only
>     (*BSR_UNICODE)   any Unicode newline sequence
> ```
>
> These override the default and the options given to  pcre_compile()  or
>          pcre_compile2(),  but  they  can  be  overridden  by  options  given to
>          pcre_exec() or pcre_dfa_exec(). Note that these special settings, which
>          are  not  Perl-compatible,  are  recognized only at the very start of a
>          pattern, and that they must be in upper case. If more than one of  them
>          is present, the last one is used. They can be combined with a change of
>          newline convention; for example, a pattern can start with:
>
> ```
>     (*ANY)(*BSR_ANYCRLF)
> ```
>
> They can also be combined with the (*UTF8) or (*UCP) special sequences.
>          Inside  a  character  class,  \R  is  treated as an unrecognized escape
>          sequence, and so matches the letter "R" by default, but causes an error
>          if PCRE_EXTRA is set.

Comment: You can also use PHP_EOL to match the installations end of file. preg_replace('~\R~u', PHP_EOL, $string);

Answer (score 21):

To normalize newlines I always use:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\r\n?~', "\n", $str);
```

It replaces the old Mac (`\r`) and the Windows (`\r\n`) newlines with the Unix equivalent (`\n`).

I preffer using `\n` because it only takes one byte instead of two, but you can easily change it to `\r\n`.

Answer (score 11):

How about

```
$sNicetext = preg_replace('/\r\n|\r|\n/', "\r\n", $sNicetext);
```

Comment: Second string needs double quotes ;)

Comment: No, it doesn't. http://www.ideone.com/xZLsx - Why do you think it should need double quotes?

Comment: Because escape sequences are parsed only in double quotes. It's okay for regex because that parses escape sequences extra, but not for all other strings. Thus the second argument needs double quotes, otherwise you will output plain \r\n, instead of a newline

Comment: False. Variables are only interpolated in double quotes. Escape sequences work everywhere.

Comment: @Tomalek http://codepad.viper-7.com/XJpmkP (And as you don't trust me, have a look at the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Wow. This... *you* just put that there! ;) Honestly, I'm totally surprised. I was so sure that variable interpolation was the only difference, I didn't even bother looking it up. Okay, thanks. Learned something. :-) -- and fixed my code sample.

Answer (score 5):

i think the smartest/simplest way to convert to CRLF is:

```
$output = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", str_replace("\r", '', $input));
```

to convert to LF only:

```
$output = str_replace("\r", '', $input);
```

it's much more easier than regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$sNicetext = str_replace(["\r\n", "\r"], "\n", $sNicetext);
```

also works

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it