# regex expression broke by line break

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression that grabs all of the text between the HTML tags `<code>` and `</code>`, which works:

```
$text = '<code><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">bc</code>d';

$code = preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);
if ($code == 1)
{
...
```

But when I add a newline to the code:

```
$text = '<code> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
bc</code>d';
```

it breaks.

Comment: Because this question is asking for regex pattern support, but doesn't actually express the implemented pattern -- it is Unclear / Needs Debugging Details and makes a poor dupe target for future questions.

Comment: Canonical dupe target: [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159118/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is apparently using a dot `.`, which by default means "any character besides newline". It can be changed to mean "any character all" by using the `/s` modifier, `PCRE_DOTALL`; see http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php.

Answer (score 0):

You should [read the documentation](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php). Your pattern probably needs a modifier so as to handle multiple lines.

It is also not a good idea to parse HTML with a regular expression. Use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you should use `(\n|(\r\n)|\r)?`

Comment: This worked: $regex = '/<code>(.*)<\/code>/msU'; Of course I want the best solution, so I'm going to look into the other solutions more thoroughly, but anyway, thanks all. oh, and it also does multiple lines

Comment: Usually, dot does not match newlines. you can use '/<code>([\s\S]*)<\/code>/msU'. \S metacharacter is used to find a non-whitespace character and \s metacharacter is used to find a whitespace character

Comment: You're mixing up solutions.  `/<code>.*<\/code>/s` will work because the `s` modifier allows `.` to match newlines (the `m` and `U` are irrelevant).  Replacing the dot with `[\s\S]` works too, but you generally see that only in JavaScript, which doesn't support the `s` modifier.

Comment: [See the metacharacter: `\R`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836692/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

```
function contentDisplay($text)
{
    //replace UTF-8
    $convertUT8 = array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6");
    $to = array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...');
    $text = str_replace($convertUT8,$to,$text);

    //replace Windows-1252
    $convertWin1252 = array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(133));
    $to = array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...');
    $text = str_replace($convertWin1252,$to,$text);

    //replace accents
    $convertAccents = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'Ð', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', '?', '?', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', '?', '?', 'L', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', '?', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'Œ', 'œ', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'Š', 'š', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Ÿ', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Ž', 'ž', '?', 'ƒ', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?');
    $to = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o');
    $text = str_replace($convertAccents,$to,$text);

    //Encode the characters
    $text = htmlentities($text);

    //normalize the line breaks (here because it applies to all text)
    $text = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $text);
    $text = str_replace("\r", "\n", $text);

    //decode the <code> tags
    $codeOpen = htmlentities('<').'code'.htmlentities('>');
    if (strpos($text, $codeOpen))
    {
        $text = str_replace($codeOpen, html_entity_decode(htmlentities('<')) . "code" . html_entity_decode(htmlentities('>')), $text);
    }
    $codeOpen = htmlentities('<').'/code'.htmlentities('>');
    if (strpos($text, $codeOpen))
    {
        $text = str_replace($codeOpen, html_entity_decode(htmlentities('<')) . "/code" . html_entity_decode(htmlentities('>')), $text);
    }

    //match everything between <code> and </code>, the msU is what makes this work here, ADD this to REGEX archive
    $regex = '/<code>(.*)<\/code>/msU';
    $code = preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);
    if ($code == 1)
    {
        if (is_array($matches) && count($matches) >= 2)
        {
            $newcode = $matches[1];

            $newcode = nl2br($newcode);
        }

    //remove <code>and this</code> from $text;
    $text = str_replace('<code>' . $matches[1] . '</code>', 'PLACEHOLDERCODE1', $text);

    //convert the line breaks to paragraphs
    $text = '<p>' . str_replace("\n\n", '</p><p>', $text) . '</p>';
    $text = str_replace("\n" , '<br />', $text);
    $text = str_replace('</p><p>', '</p>' . "\n\n" . '<p>', $text);

    $text = str_replace('PLACEHOLDERCODE1', '<code>'.$newcode.'</code>', $text);
    }
    else
    {
        $code = false;
    }

    if ($code == false)
    {
        //convert the line breaks to paragraphs
        $text = '<p>' . str_replace("\n\n", '</p><p>', $text) . '</p>';
        $text = str_replace("\n" , '<br />', $text);
        $text = str_replace('</p><p>', '</p>' . "\n\n" . '<p>', $text);
    }

    return $text;
}
```