# character separator for newline textarea

Tags: php, newline, carriage-return

So evidently:

```
\n = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Unix
\r = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS
\r\n = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows
(char)13 = \n = CR // Same as \n
```

but then I also heard that for HTML textarea, when it's submitted and parsed by a php script, all new lines are converted to \r\n regardless of the platform

is this true and can I rely on this or am I completely mistaken?

ie. if I wanna do explode() based on a new line, can I use '\r\n' as the delimiter regardless of whether or not the user is using mac, pc, etc

Comment: Not true, but see here: [How to replace different newline styles in PHP the smartest way?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7836632/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All newlines should be converted in `\r\n` by [the spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1).

So you could indeed do a simple `explode("\r\n", $theContent)` no matter the platform used.

P.S.

`\r` is only used on old(er) Macs. Nowadays Macs also use the *nix style line breaks (`\n`).

Answer (score 1):

You could try preg_split, which will use a regular expression to split up the string. Within this regular expression you can match on all 3 new line variants.

```
$ArrayOfResults = preg_split( '/\r\n|\r|\n/', $YourStringToExplode );
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you are doing this eventually to display / format it as HTML, you can as well use the [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br) function or possibly use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) like this:

```
$val = str_replace( array("\n","\r","\r\n"), '<br />', $val );
```

In case you want to just get an array of all lines, I would suggest you use all 3 characters ("\n","\r","\r\n") for explode