# How I can remove new lines only inside the HTML tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

How I can remove new lines only inside the HTML tags with preg_replace ?

Example:

```
<table>

<tr>

<td></td>
</tr>
</table>

Text here. Text here

Text here.
```

So after the functions process the above code the return should be:

```
<table>    <tr>    <td></td>    </tr>    </table>

Text here. Text here

Text here.
```

Comment: `remove new lines only inside the HTML tags`: That's really innovative, why do you want to do this?

Comment: You can't. Sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1220835

Comment: This is not actually parsing entire page, just small HTML code.

Comment: only the following tags are available: table, ol,li,ul,a,blockquoute, tr,td,tbody

Answer (score 2):

> How I can remove new lines only inside the HTML tags with preg_replace ?

Technically yes, but actually, HTML does not care for newlines that much, every multiple whitespace characters are actually read as a single one. As your example shows, you replace \n with space or \t, so it's actually the same which brings me to the point you can just do the following:

```
$html = preg_replace('~(>[^>]*)(*BSR_ANYCRLF)\R([^<]*<)~', '$1 $3', $html);
```

See as well: [php regex to match outside of html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7891771/367456) and [How to replace different newline styles in PHP the smartest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7836632/367456).

A more safe way is to use a HTML parser like `DOMDocument` and load your fragment as body. Then replace all newlines within textnodes that are childnodes of body childnodes.

Comment: I get the following error:

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: (*VERB) not recognized at offset 13 in

Comment: @user1316394: Update your PCRE library or remove that verb (*BSR_ANYCRLF), you can add the `u` modifier instead in case the string is utf-8 encoded.

Comment: @user1316394: No Idea, I don't use simplehtmldom for different reasons and I won't suggest you to use it either. Take a look at [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) and/or [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/SimpleXML) which are part of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There might be smarter ways to do this, but however, this will do your job.

```
$str = "test\n\n test2 <table>\n\n\n test 3</table>\n\n\n test4 test5";

while ($str2 = preg_replace('/(>[^<]*)\n([^<]*<)/', '\\1\\2', $str)) {
    if ($str2 == $str) break;
    $str = $str2;
}

echo ($str);
```

It looks for newlines in between the > char and the < char, and removes them.

Comment: Hi, what about if there are actually chars like: > and < in page?

Comment: I have tested the code and it also replaces text between outer html elements:
<ul>

<li>efewf
</li>

</ul>

Test test test test test.
Test test test test test.

Test test test test test.

<ul>

<li>efewf
</li>

</ul>

Comment: cod between the first </ul> and the second <ul> have their new lines removed,

Comment: So you only want to remove new lines if there are no child elements inside the element?

Comment: @user1316394: That's because that text is *between* the first and second `<ul>` tag - which you have *asked*  for.

Comment: @user1316394: If you want to have control over how deep down in the xml you are, you should use something like `DOMDocument`. Just using regexp, that would be a (close to) impossible task.

Comment: If there are actually chars like: > and < in page that is not part of an element, your HTML is very bad and your web browser might go nuts. < should be encoded as &lt; and > as &gt;