# How can I get multiline match to work on NOWDOC strings?

Tags: php

I get this:

```
  $p= <<<'EOD'
stuff
more
EOD;
  print (preg_match ('~^stuff$~m', $p)); // expected 1, got 0
```

despite

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> the "start of line" and "end of line" constructs match immediately
>   following or immediately before any newline in the subject string,
>   respectively

EDIT: This is in a standard Windows text file.

Comment: you should use '/' instead of '~' for the start and end of the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely using CRLF or CR instead of just a line feed for line breaks. Switch to using LF only or [normalize your string to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836632/how-to-replace-different-newline-styles-in-php-the-smartest-way) prior to running through `preg_match` and what you've got will [just work.](https://3v4l.org/DgQ1G)

Comment: Thanks. This works on Windows: print (preg_match ('~^stuff$~m', str_replace("\x0d\x0A","\x0A",$p))); though I would like a solution for all platforms... and oddly normaising to PHP_EOL fails.