# php strlen() getting different value on different environments for same string

Tags: php, xml, linux, windows

I have a long xml string that I am getting the length of to do a comparison. On the Linux Environment, it gets a value of 2788, but on Windows Environment, it's getting 2860. I have diff'ed the output, and they appear to be the same string. 
I have also tried `htmlentities` for the debug and `utf8_decode` on the string before doing the comparison, but no change in result. Why is this disparity here?

```
var_dump($xml);
print_r($xml);
print_r(htmlentities($architype_xml));
echo strlen(utf8_decode($xml));
echo strlen($xml);
```

Also, I don't believe I see a difference in new lines, but perhaps var_dump and print_r isn't giving me the full picture, I'm unsure how else to check.

Comment: `they __appear__ to be the same string`... therein likely lies the problem.... Are there perhaps html entities in the string that might be interpreted by the browser, but interpreted by the back-end in the other?

Comment: windows vs. linux new lines, windows takes 2 characters for a newline while linux takes one

Comment: @MarkBaker, already tested for that before, updated my answer.

Comment: Hex dump the two strings, and compare them byte-by-byte

Comment: Also double-check the `php.ini` setting `mbstring.func_overload` on both servers, as this can change the behaviour of `strlen()` - http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php - really, there's very little justification ever to have it set to anything other than 0

Comment: i suggest you normalize the line endings before working with the file, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836632/how-to-replace-different-newline-styles-in-php-the-smartest-way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probable newline characters in windows being "\n\r" and only "\n" on linux?

can you give us the string ?

EDIT:
To remove the EndOfLines

```
$xml = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $xml)
```

Comment: How would I accommodate for this in my code? It's private data, but it happens with several string, not just the one in my example.

Comment: remove newlines "\n" and "\r" characters

Comment: That's exactly correct. Upvote for now, but if you update your question with the solution of removing \n and \r characters, I'll mark it as a correct answer. I used `$xml = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $xml)`