# Golang - Removing all Unicode newline characters from a string

Tags: go, unicode, utf-8

How do I remove all Unicode newlines from a UTF-8 string in GoLang? I found [this answer for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836692/49560).

Comment: What's a "Unicode newline"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode

Comment: t := strings.TrimSpace(s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`strings.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map):

```
func filterNewLines(s string) string {
    return strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
        switch r {
        case 0x000A, 0x000B, 0x000C, 0x000D, 0x0085, 0x2028, 0x2029:
            return -1
        default:
            return r
        }
    }, s)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/43I9ckDVzH)