# How to use str_replace with a condition

Tags: php, html, str-replace

I want to use str_replace with some conditions. 
I am developing an application which inputs a block of text from a text area and output it as 1 line. Whenever an "`end of line`" or "`space + with end of line`" is met, the string is replaced by `<br>`

I have now came with the solution that whenever and `end of line` is met, the string is replaced by `<br>`. But if the user types a `space` before `end of line` , i need to get rid of that space too before replacing the EOL with `<br>`.

> **MY CODE**

```
$refresheddata = str_replace("\n", '<br>', $data);
```

> **SAMPLE INPUT**

```
This is the first line with a space at the end 
This is the second line which donot have a space at the end
```

> **OUTPUT OF MY CODE**

```
This is the first line with a space at the end <br>This is the second line which donot have a space at the end
```

> **REQUIRED OUTPUT**

```
This is the first line with a space at the end<br>This is the second line which donot have a space at the end
```

Check the space before `<br>`

> FULL CODE

```
<?php 
$page = $data = $title =  $refresheddata = '';
if($_POST){
    $page = $_POST['page'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $refresheddata = str_replace("\n", '<br>', $data);
    $refresheddata = htmlentities($refresheddata);
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <h3>Original Text</h3>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter your title here.." style="font-size:16px; padding:10px;" required><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="page" placeholder="Enter your page data here.." style="font-size:16px; padding:10px;" required><br><br>
    <textarea name="data" rows="15" style="width:100%" placeholder="Enter your remaining contents here..." required></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form><br><br>

<h3>Result Text</h3>
&lt;START&gt;<br>
&lt;TITLE&gt;<?php echo $title; ?>&lt;/TITLE&gt;<br>
&lt;BODY&gt;<br>
&lt;P&gt;<?php echo $page; ?>&lt;/P&gt;<br>
&lt;P&gt;<?php echo $refresheddata; ?>&lt;/P&gt;<br>
&lt;/BODY&gt;<br>
&lt;END&gt;
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use `nl2br()`?

Comment: @Quirel it still wouldn't handle the space char

Comment: Since you produce HTML, the white space before `<br>` doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. Since Im using textarea for the input, all other answers are wrong, I still get the space at the EOL.
I tried replacing my str_replace functions parameters and got the desired output.

> SOLUTION

```
$refresheddata = str_replace(array(" \r\n","\r\n"), '<br>', $data);
```

Now the new line is gone with the space before it.

Answer (score 5):

The easy way, just replace both :

```
$refresheddata = str_replace([" \n","\n"], '<br>', $data);
```

It can also be done with a simple regexp, like this one

```
$refresheddata = preg_replace("/ ?\n/",'<br>',$data);
```

The regexp solution might be more versatile as it can also be updated to handle slightly different other cases as well, such as more than one space preceding a newline at the same time. Choose acording to your needs and how you will be better able to maintain the code.

Comment: Note that the order is important if you use `str_replace` otherwise the spaces will not go away

Comment: Issue is not resolved. I have updated the question with full code.

Comment: See this demo : https://3v4l.org/ciXIs the solution does work acording to the initial context you provided. The data going through your form changes the game somewhat (newlines might not just be simple \n chars, etc)

Comment: see this question (and answers) for a lead to your new problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836632/how-to-replace-different-newline-styles-in-php-the-smartest-way

Comment: @Calimero Thanks for the answer. Since i'm taking my input from a text box, you solution doesn't work. I have searched and came up with the answer.