# Handling textarea new Lines using JS formData to PHP backend

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a website running PHP 7.4 on ubuntu 20.04 with a form with a textarea element. Here is how it is setup.

```
<form id="user-input">
<textarea name="usertags">
</textarea>
</form>
```

When the user clicks the submit button, I am doing a POST fetch request using **FormData** and **JSON.stringify** in Javascript

```
formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("user-input"));
async function postUserAction(formData) {
   const response = await fetch('https://example.com/action.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData))
   });
      return await response.json();
```

On the PHP backend

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
$tags= explode(PHP_EOL, $data->usertags);
```

Now, my question is if the **PHP_EOL** is cross platform safe regardless of what browser/system/device the user is using? I am storing the tags in a database so I need to be able to get consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

`PHP_EOL` is platform dependent, meaning it corresponds to `\r\n` on Windows and `\n` on others. As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836632/how-to-replace-different-newline-styles-in-php-the-smartest-way), you can try normalizing the newlines first:

```php
$usrTags = preg_replace('~\R~u', "\n", $data->usertags);
```

and then do the explode:

```php
$tags= explode("\n", $usrTags);
```

Since your data is coming from clientside browsers, I very much doubt you will find anything other than "\n", so you could just be fine with replacing `PHP_EOL` with `\n` instead of normalizing.