# A string from text field - php does not explode it on the same way

Tags: php, explode

here is the content inside a mysql table - column type text:

```
lorem ipsum

* * *

dolor sit
```

I got it using php as a string variable and want to explode it by two consecutive line ends

```
$arr = explode("\n\n", $str);
echo count($arr) // 3
```

Now, another row has the same content and `echo count($arr)` gives `1`

I suppose something is wrong with end of lines, but how can I check this and how to ensure that in the future all end of lines to be the same?

Comment: Please make runnable case

Comment: _"Now, anothe row has the same content"_ - "looks the same when rendered as HTML", does not have to mean _is_ exactly the same. The most likely explanation here would probably be, that this one is using `\r\n` for line breaks.

Comment: Debug your code. For example, use `var_dump($str);` to see the actual, literal content of the string (not just how it's interpreted by a HTML parser (i.e. your browser). Then you can predict what will happen to it when you run explode().

Comment: _"and how to ensure that in the future all end of lines to be the same?"_ - [How to replace different newline styles in PHP the smartest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7836632/1427878)

Comment: `echo rawurlencode($str)` also helps to debug what exactly you're looking at.

Comment: @CBroe - How to unify all ends of lines in a string? I cannot use `PP_EOL` because I need two consecutive ends

Comment: _"I cannot use PP_EOL because I need two consecutive ends"_ - `PHP_EOL` is _one_ line break, in a OS-specific format. So why could you not use this then, if you needed two consecutive line breaks? That would be _one_ `PHP_EOL`, immediately followed by a _second_ `PHP_EOL` then. Why do you think that would be _any_ different, from having two line breaks explicitly expressed as `\n\n` in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe - I need to explode the string by two consecutive ends. `$arr = explode(PHP_EOLPHP_EOL, $str);` - will not work

Comment: Of course not, because a constant named `PHP_EOLPHP_EOL` does not exist. How do we concatenate two values again in PHP, in a string context ...? `PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL`

Comment: @CBroe - I tried `$arr = explode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, $str);` The first string is exploded correctly (3 items), and the second - again just 1 item. Something is deeply wrong with end of lines in that column

Comment: Don't guess, *see.* Again: `echo rawurlencode($str)`.

Comment: @deceze - I tried `rawurlencode`. In the first string end of lines are `%0D%0A`. Second - `%0A`. How to unify them ?

Comment: `$str = str_replace("\r", '', $str)`…?

Comment: @deceze - It works finally. Thanks a lot. Give me please some reference link where I can see that `%0D%0A` means `\r` and similar

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation